# Include custom WWW-Authenticate header in 401 Unauthorised response when using Microsoft.Identity.Web

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-identity-web

Following instructions on making MS Office connect to my Asp.NET Core Web API, I am attempting to present a login redirect to MS Office for failed authentications.  Following [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66015222/how-to-implement-organizational-account-authentication-in-excel-on-server-side) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226782/10340388) I am attempting to include the login redirect information in the `WWW-Authenticate` header property.  My Web API is protected with Azure AD and the [`Microsoft.Identity.Web`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web) library.  When the authentication fails and the middleware returns the 401 Unauthorized response, the header does include the `WWW-Authenticate` property but it's value is only `Bearer`.

**Q:** How can update the header information to include the necessary additional redirect information?

I have tried to implement an attribute on the API, derived from `IAsyncAuthorizationFilter` and access the response header in that.  However the middleware already returns a 401 before this attribute is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original answer put me on the right track. It turned out to be actually quite simple to do this once I knew to configure the `JwtBearerOptions.Challenge` property:

```cs
services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Challenge = $"Bearer authorization_uri=\"{authorizationUri}\"";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made progress by customizing the `JwtBearerOptions` configuration.  However this approach creates an additional header item, instead of overwriting the standard value.  As a result I have now 2 KeyValuePairs for the same key in the response header, which will likely have unexpected outcomes.

In my Startup.cs:

```c
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration)

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    var existingOnChallengeHandler = options.Events.OnChallenge;
    options.Events.OnChallenge = async context =>
    {
        await existingOnChallengeHandler(context);

        string headerInfo = context.Options.Challenge;
        headerInfo += " resource=\"https://management.azure.com/\"";
        context.Response.Headers.Append(HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate, headerInfo);
    };
});
```